# How to detect and recognize information on documents using neural networks?

Tags: neural-network, conv-neural-network

I am facing the following problem:

I have scanned documents which include data which I partly want to detect and some other data which is not interesting to us.

The documents could look like this one:
[image: Document]

Now, I am only interested to get the First and the last name of a person and his address. All the other information is not important. Now, I am wondering how to get this information by using neural networks. I think the first step needs to be the information extraction by using e.g. the YOLO network. So, the YOLO network should localize this information using bounding boxes as illustrated in the graphics:

[image: YOLO]
After extracting the information it needs to be recognized. So, I think this could be a similar approach as it is in License plate recognition where the license plate is at first localized and afterwards it gets recognized, correct?

So, the second step would be to recognize the localized information, which would be this one:

[image: Name and address]

I think this approach is very similar to some approaches for invoice processing.
Or is there a completely different approach? Maybe by digitizing the document at first and afterwards using natural language processing to get the information?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is something like the Google Cloud Vision API an option? It can detect and read text and return the text it found. Then it's a simple search in the results for firstname: and surname:

You can try a demo with your image here:

https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/drag-and-drop

To answer your comment:

Take a look at this: https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/ocr essentially you get a JSON object back with an array of items found called textAnnotations. The example they give is:

```
      "textAnnotations": [
    {
      "locale": "en",
      "description": "WAITING?\nPLEASE\nTURN OFF\nYOUR\nENGINE\n",
      "boundingPoly": {
        "vertices": [
          {
            "x": 341,
            "y": 828
          },
          {
            "x": 2249,
            "y": 828
          },
          {
            "x": 2249,
            "y": 1993
          },
          {
            "x": 341,
            "y": 1993
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "description": "WAITING?",
      "boundingPoly": {
        "vertices": [
          {
            "x": 352,
            "y": 828
          },
          {
            "x": 2248,
            "y": 911
          },
          {
            "x": 2238,
            "y": 1148
          },
          {
            "x": 342,
            "y": 1065
          }
        ]
      }
    }, etc etc ....
```

So all you need to do is loop through the array and find the ones that come after First name: and Surname. Sudo code below:

```
var firstname = "", surname = "";    
for( var i=0; i < response.textAnnotations.length; i++) {
  if ( response.textAnnotations[i].description == "First name:" ) firstname = response.textAnnotations[i + 1].description;
}
```

Hope that makes sense!

Comment: Thanks! Yes, this is a good tool for digitizing a document. What technique would you use to look for the needed information?